# Wine update error

Tags: updates, wine

I'm totally new to elementary OS and Linux. I've decided to have a go at elementary as the OS for a new self build media PC.

I'm pretty chuffed that I've muddle along so far and got quite a few things working. One of the main requirements before ditching the idea and opting for Windows 10 was to get music sounding pretty good. On my previous media PC I used `Winamp` set on full treble and bass preset equaliser and that's what I was trying to replicate.

So I've done an adjusted copy `PulseAudio` conf file and tweaked ALSA. I then experimented with importing `Winamp` equaliser presets into Audacious. I then found out that I could use Wine and install some Windows stuff, so this is what I've done and installed `Winamp` - and comparing `Audacious` and `Wimanp` next to each other then, once again, `Winamp` just wins out.

However, this is all at the very edge of my understanding anything about Linux. I installed Wine through AppCenter and it said in there that it was installed. But when I clicked on the `Winamp.exe` then Wine was not there as the default program, nor was it in the list to chose from as an alternative program. So, I found out that I had to navigate to the `.exe` folder using the terminal and then typing wine `winamp.exe`.

Now, when I open [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) I keep getting this fetch error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. 
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

No matter how many times I hit Ignore it pops up again after a few seconds and it making [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) pretty much unusable.

How can I correct for this error? Do I uninstall `Wine` and have another go? Do I have to uninstall `Winamp` first if I do? Please bear in mind I don't understand much of the jargon of Linux, and my knowledge of most things is still pretty much zero. I vaguely understand that a [ppa](/questions/tagged/ppa) is an online set of files that get updated and so elementary goes to check for updates every so often. Googling this error message so far implies that Wine should not even have worked, so I don't know what's going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

About the repository

Run the following commands on a terminal window

- `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

  - (removing the PPA `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`)
- `wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -`

  - (downloading and adding to the system the GPG key of WineHQ's repository)
- `sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'`

  - (adding [apt](/questions/tagged/apt) WineHQ's repository)
- `sudo apt update`

  - (update [apt](/questions/tagged/apt) Release/Package lists of the repositories)
- `sudo apt install wine-stable`

  - (install Wine using [apt](/questions/tagged/apt))

---

- If you get an error like `NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F` or `GPG Error` try with:

  - `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 76F1A20FF987672F`

    - (This will download the GPG key from the a keyserver to [apt](/questions/tagged/apt))

---

From: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

> !!! PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED !!!
>
> In fact, it's double deprecated -- it was replaced by the Wine Builds PPA, which was then itself replaced.
>
> For more information, please see:
>
> ```
>    https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html
> ```
>
> The following commands can be used to add the new repository:
>
> ```
>    wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
>    sudo apt-key add Release.key
>    sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
> ```

---

One more thing, read this answer:

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17075/14940

---

### About [apt](/questions/tagged/apt)

https://itsfoss.com/apt-get-linux-guide/

Note: Nowadays we use `apt` instead of `apt-get`

- `apt` is user oriented
- `apt-get` low level command

Sometimes you'll need to use those low level commands but for the majority of situations just stick with just `apt`

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian I'll give this a go. Most things I've googled to help me get things up and running have involved using terminal rather than appcentre

Comment: I'll comment every command above for you to learn what it does.

Comment: ¬Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is a virtual package provided by:
  wine-stable 3.0-1ubuntu1
  wine-development 3.6-1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate¬

Comment: Hi again. Sorry, I can't figure out what character makes text look like code - it's obviously not ' or ¬ Anyway, I've followed the instructions and I got this message after the last line

Comment: `W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F    
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.   
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.   
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: I tried it myself and yes It doesn't work like the wine website says (their fault) but now after I ran a command (read above) it works. And the package is called `wine-stable`

Comment: This all seems to have worked but now Winamp isn't there - clicking on the icon does nothing. I've gone to my donwloads directory in terminal and typed `wine winamp5666_full_all.exe` as before and it now says   `Command 'wine' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install wine-development
sudo apt install wine-stable `

Comment: I think installing the wine-development bit seems to have got me up and running again.

Comment: Well that part of "how wine works" you should ask them (their support channel), at least with my answer you could install the proper version of wine from the (now) official repository. I see you are now using the terminal with ease, that's good keep it up.